# Remove Numbers in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have here a text file
with

```
245. asdasd
45. asdasd
42. gfhfgh
5353. sdfsdf
```

want to remove all numbers in front of it.
try it already with find and replace [0-9].

Comment: what about `\d+\.` as the search term?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Ctrl+F - Replace - Search mode: regular expression

Find What: [0-9]+

Replace With:

// Replace with is empty

Answer (score 14):

`Ctrl-H` - shows replace.

Ensure that 'regular expression' is on.

Use `^[0-9]+`

**Note** begging ^ used to mark begin of line. Remove it if need remove all numbers

Comment: Even though this is old, This should be marked as the correct answer! 
"^[0-9]+" will only do the start of a line for people who have copied source code from a website who does not allow a plain text view.
"[0-9]+" will replace ANY NUMBERS!

Answer (score 4):

use RegEx search (should be `^\d+` for numbers with more than 1 digit):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the replace tab switch to regular expressions; *Search for* `^\d+\.\s` and leave *Replace With* empty.

(Matches start of line, any number, a dot, trailing space)

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use this regular expression to remove what you want in the replace dialog:

```
^[0-9]*\.\ (.*)
```

And replace with:

```
\1
```

Comment: Don't forget to anchor it to the beginning of the line or hilarity may ensue.

Answer (score 3):

To search for digits:

1. Find what:  [[:d:]]
2. Select:  o Regular Expression

Answer (score 0):

To remove only "line numbers with dots" use
[0-9]+.

Answer (score 0):

To remove digits only from start of string

```
Input : 123. asdasd 3434
Output: . asdasd 3434
```

Replace All using below regex with o or more spaces in start of string

```
^\s*\d+
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

**For Numbers**
Ctrl H
Find what: [0-9]
Replace With:
(leave replace with blank)

**For Period**
Ctrl H
Find what: .
Replace With:
(leave replace with blank)

Comment: How is this better than other answers?