# How do I format a complex large textfile and remove multiple types of characters

Tags: regex, text

**Background:**
I am dealing with this huge text file: http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt

The first ten lines look like this, with `\t` representing a tab in the file:

```
id\tnm\tlat\tlon\tcountryCode
819827\tRazvilka\t55.591667\t37.740833\tRU
524901\tMoscow\t55.752220\t37.615555\tRU
1271881\tFirozpur Jhirka\t27.799999\t76.949997\tIN
1283240\tKathmandu\t27.716667\t85.316666\tNP
703448\tKiev\t50.433334\t30.516666\tUA
1282898\tPokhara\t28.233334\t83.983330\tNP
3632308\tMerida\t8.598333\t-71.144997\tVE
1273294\tDelhi\t28.666668\t77.216667\tIN
502069\tReshetnikovo\t56.450001\t36.566666\tRU
```

I want to remove all characters in this text file except the names (the second tabbed element after the city id)

**What I have tried so far:**

- Find and replace [0-9]+ with "" : discovered from ([Remove Numbers in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310086/remove-numbers-in-notepad))
- Find and replace "-" with ""
- Find and replace "." with ""

**What I can't figure out**

- I need to remove all the excess spaces, but I cant find and replace space to "" because some of the names have spaces in them.
- I need to remove the country codes (ex. RU, UK, US, etc), maybe using some regex to find 2 letters in a row and deleting them?

**Current state of file after my efforts (A small extraction)**

```
Ciudad Bolivar          VE
Marfino         RU
Zhukovskiy          RU
Reutov          RU
Kurovskoye          RU
Zheleznodorozhnyy           RU
Golitsyno           RU
Petrozavodsk            RU
Saint Petersburg            RU
Klimovsk            RU
Novosibirsk         RU
Donetsk         UA
Istra           RU
Bakhchysaray            UA
Chekhov         RU
Lyubuchany          RU
Vostryakovo         RU
Boryspil            UA
```

Comment: Lucky you to be able to consider a 3 MiB file as 'huge'.    Add a couple of orders of magnitude and yes, maybe.  But that is small enough to fit in main memory without the machine blinking.

Comment: You can use `\s+[A-Z]{2}$` to match the spaces and the country code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `cut -f2` or `awk -F $'\t' '{print $2}'` you've got the entire job done.  Both print the second column in a tab-separated file.

Failing that, you could use Bash and:

```
sed $'s/^[^\t]*\t\([^\t]*\)\t.*/\\1/'
```

That uses Bash's [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to generate the regex.  The `$'…'` encloses the ANSI C quoted string.  The regex then matches start of line, zero or more non-tabs, a tab, starts remembering, zero or more non-tabs, stops remembering, a tab and anything else on the line, and replaces it with just the remembered text.  That is the city name from column 2 of the file.

It would be easier to write:

```
sed "s/^[^⎵]*⎵\([^⎵]*\)⎵.*/\1/"
```

where I'm using `⎵` to represent a tab.  To type the tabs at the command line, you might need to use <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Control-I</kbd> to get each tab entered (because Bash otherwise treats the tab as filename completion).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Notepad++ to perform this task, do a simple search-and-replace with the following regex:

```
[0-9]+\t([-A-Za-z ]+)\t-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\t-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\t[A-Z]{2}
```

And replace with `\1`.

Alternatively, from the command-line:

```
perl -pe "s/[0-9]+\t([-A-Za-z ]+)\t-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\t-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\t[A-Z]{2}/\1/" city_list.txt > city_list_clean.txt
```

Comment: Can you not compress the with notations such as `\d` for digits, and `[^\t]` for "not a tab", etc?  And you don't need to validate the latitude, longitude or country code fields if you are going to ignore them.  Those changes would simplify the Perl regex.  Though you could also use splitting and specify the tab as the split character: `perl -lne '@f = split /\t/; print $f[1]'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure why I used `[0-9]` instead of `\d`. Otherwise I decided not to include a more abstract regex using `[^\t]` because your answer already provided one. I am still learning so I appreciate your criticism! :-)

Comment: I'm still learning too — you only stop once you're dead.  The second edition of my answer has a much simpler ANSI C quoting sequence in it than the first edition did; I learned too.