# Remove Numbers - more than 3 digits- in Notepad++

Tags: numbers, notepad++

i found how to remove numbers in Notepad++ here
[Remove Numbers in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310086/remove-numbers-in-notepad)
and the solution was:`[0-9]+`
thats good but in the file i have i wanna just remove +3 digits

for example:

```
123
456
789
```

but the numbers less than 3 digits remain in the file.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex instead

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]+
```