# Remove Numbers in the first 1-3 spaces in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

A very similar issue to [Remove Numbers in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310086/remove-numbers-in-notepad)

Except in my case I wish to only delete the bold numbers in front.

As far as I know, the only regex I know how to use for this deletes all numbers in a text file, however I need the middle three numbers kept.

Here is an excerpt from a file that has thousands of similar lines.

**9**;0;4;248;sea;false;ocean;0

**13**;0;8;244;sea;false;ocean;0

**489**;0;10;232;sea;true;ocean;0

How can I delete the first numbers that have 1-3 characters without deleting the numbers in between the semi colons?

Comment: Remove everything between the start of the line and the first semi-colon?

Answer (score 1):

using the following regular expression to match then replace them to empty, it  seems to work for you to delete the first numbers that have 1-3 characters

```
^\d{1,3}
```

Answer (score 1):

To match the first 1-3 digits you could use `^\d{1,3}`.

If you only want to match those followed by a semicolon you could add a positive lookahead `(?=;)` to assert what follows is a semicolon.

`^\d{1,3}(?=;)`

Instead of a positive lookahead you could also match `^\d{1,3}` followed by capturing the semicolon in a capturing group `(;)` and in the replacement use group 1.

`^\d{1,3}(;)`

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions seem to work so
from
"^[\d]*;"
to
""
without the quotes will strip all leading digits and the first semicolon